# How do I change a variable in a .js file from a .html file?

Tags: javascript, html

```
  var text = "hello";
```

this is a variable that's in my .js file

```
<script src="variablesAndFunctions.js" type="text/javascript">

   text = "something other then hello";

</script>
```

this is the script tag that declares a new value for the variable

I've also tried to declare it inside a separate script tag in the same html file like so

```
<script type="javascript">  

    text = "something other then hello"

</script>
```

but when I console.log it it just returns hello.

How do I fix this? any help would be appreciated.

edit1:

this is my actual code on my variablesAndFunctions.js file

```
var number = 0;

var text = "hello";

var speed = 30;

function writeText() {

  if (number < text.length) {
    document.getElementById("gameText").innerHTML += text.charAt(number);
    number++;
    setTimeout(writeText, speed);     
  }
  //prints text and speed to console
  console.log(text + speed);

  //prints number variable to console
  console.log("number = " + number + " numberOfLetters = " + numberOfLetters);

  console.log(textTime);

  }
```

this is my html code

```
<script src="variablesAndFunctions.js" type="text/javascript">

    writeText();

    text = "something other then hello"

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = writeText();

</script>
```

I've also tried to declare the value of text in the other script tag as well

Comment: Where do you do your console.log? anyway, the first html snippet won't work as expected since the inner part is not executed because it loads the `variablesAndFunctions.js`.

Comment: The first one didn't work because code inside a script tag with a src attribute is ignored and not executed. The second might not work depending on where the original variable is declared, and if that script tags location, ie before or after the script that has the original variable in it. We would need to see more of your code to diagnose properly. Also see about making a [mcve]

Comment: @lexith i open the .html file in chrome and i print console.log(text) into the console in chrome (f12)

Comment: Can you show us the actual html markup? How do you include your external .js file and when do you add the inline scripts?

Comment: In the second javascript snippet your are missing text/. Instead of type="javascript" it should be type="text/javascript"

Comment: ... which prevents the script from being executed. just leave the `type="text/javascript"` away cause it's assumed anyway.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  We can probably suggest a much better way.

Comment: i made an edit so that its more clear

Comment: @HunterChen Thanks for the update, but you already have all the answers you need in this comment section: the stuff inside your script tag will never execute therefore your function is only called once at the onload event.

Comment: @lexith so is there a way that i can get around this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't put script inside script tags with an src attribute. The inner script will be ignored.

Comment: elaborate please, I dont really understand. I am new to coding.

Comment: Short answer, but it basically has all in it you need to know: If you put a `src` attribute to a `<script>` tag, everything between the tag is ignored (even if the provided URL to your script is wrong, then it just fails to load). This means the part where you set your `text` to `something else...` and call that function again, will never be executed.

Comment: If you write javascript code inside a script tag that has a src attribute, the inner code will be ignored. In your case the code inside this script tags:

 <script src="variablesAndFunctions.js" type="text/javascript">

is being ignored.

Comment: so is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Move the code inside your first script tag to the second, and remove the () when you assign to window.onload a function reference.

<script type="text/javascript">
    writeText();
    text = "something other then hello"
    window.onload = writeText;
</script>